Angular 18.2.0 with bootstrap 5.3.3 is not working
My Angular project is based on version 18.2.0 and I also installed Bootstrap.
The command I used is install bootstrap is :  npm install bootstrap
In angular.json I've updates the "styles array" and "scripts array".
In app.componemt.html,  I've added a simple button.
I launched the application using  "ng serve"
When opening the browser with  http://localhost:4200/ , nothing is displayed and in DevTools there is an error:
"ERROR InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'btn-primary”' is not a valid attribute name."
It seems as if Bootstrap is not loaded correctly. What is the cause that Bootstrap is not loaded ?






Can you check the validity of your HTML ?

check the quotes in the HTML, from the error it doesn't seem to pick up quotes, and it thinks class is an attribute.. (trailing curly quote in 'btn-primary”'..)

@user2023141 Could you share a github repo where the issue happens, stackblitz is also fine, code loooks ok, so something else might be wrong!

@traynor might be correct, try pasting <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Test Button </button> into app.component.html you might be using some other quotes, which is messing with the compiler

I check the quotes in the HTML, and indeed, the quotes I used were incorrect.  I changed  ”  into  " , and now the button works and no error is displayed. @
traynor, you can post your answer as the solution

Update the angular cli and create the new project. I have checked on my local, and everything is working fine

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s.

The quotes I used were incorrect. I changed ” into " , and now the button works and no error is displayed.
